# Wildfly 2x | Server resume

Tags: wildfly, ear

I am experiencing an unexpected automatic EAR restart from Wildfly 23.0.2.Final (also verified with 22.0.1.Final and 23.0.0.Final).

Basically, what happens is that the application is started, but when everything is up and running, I receive a message that reads `WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server` and the deploy process starts over again. This also seems to jeopardize JMS queues definition (defined from within the EJB module as `@JMSResourceDestination`s).

Below the snippet of the logs when this happens (just a bit anonymized):

```
13:16:12,228 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) WFLYSRV0010: Deployed "XXXX.ear" (runtime-name : "XXXX.ear")
13:16:12,250 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYJCA0019: Stopped Driver service with driver-name = XXXXX.ear_org.postgresql.Driver_42_2
13:16:12,251 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYSRV0212: Resuming server
13:16:12,260 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) WFLYUT0022: Unregistered web context: '/api' from server 'default-server'
13:16:12,269 INFO  [io.undertow.servlet] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 9) Closing Spring root WebApplicationContext
13:16:12,303 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) AMQ222061: Client connection failed, clearing up resources for session 1610e737-d282-11eb-9d4b-0242e77fb65d
13:16:12,309 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.server] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 25) AMQ222107: Cleared up resources for session 1610e737-d282-11eb-9d4b-0242e77fb65d
13:16:12,313 WARN  [org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra] (default-threads - 1) AMQ152005: Failure in broker activation org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivationSpec(ra=org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ActiveMQResourceAdapter@9f1bfbc destination=java:global/XXXX/jms/queue/queue1 destinationType=javax.jms.Queue ack=Auto-acknowledge durable=false clientID=null user=null maxSession=15): ActiveMQUnBlockedException[errorType=UNBLOCKED message=AMQ219016: Connection failure detected. Unblocking a blocking call that will never get a response]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:540)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ChannelImpl.sendBlocking(ChannelImpl.java:434)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:300)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.protocol.core.impl.ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.createSessionContext(ActiveMQClientProtocolManager.java:249)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionChannel(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1401)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSessionInternal(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:705)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createSession(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:316)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.ActiveMQResourceAdapter.createSession(ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java:1602)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivation.setupSession(ActiveMQActivation.java:491)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivation.setup(ActiveMQActivation.java:316)
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra@2.16.0//org.apache.activemq.artemis.ra.inflow.ActiveMQActivation$SetupActivation.run(ActiveMQActivation.java:764)
    at org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq//org.wildfly.extension.messaging.activemq.ActiveMQResourceAdapter$WorkWrapper.run(ActiveMQResourceAdapter.java:161)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.runWork(WorkWrapper.java:445)
    at org.jboss.as.connector@23.0.2.Final//org.jboss.as.connector.services.workmanager.WildflyWorkWrapper.runWork(WildflyWorkWrapper.java:69)
    at org.jboss.ironjacamar.impl@1.4.27.Final//org.jboss.jca.core.workmanager.WorkWrapper.run(WorkWrapper.java:223)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.SimpleDirectExecutor.execute(SimpleDirectExecutor.java:29)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.runTask(QueueExecutor.java:789)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor.access$100(QueueExecutor.java:44)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.QueueExecutor$Worker.run(QueueExecutor.java:809)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
    at org.jboss.threads@2.4.0.Final//org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:513)

13:16:12,329 INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.messaging-activemq] (MSC service thread 1-5) WFLYMSGAMQ0006: Unbound messaging object to jndi name java:global/XXXX/jms/queue/queue1
```

The EAR was created with the specific Wildfly archetype. The configuration of the Wildfly instance is the `standalone-full`, as it comes out of the box.

Anyone who can help me understand what's happening?

---

## UPDATE: Wildfly logs

Increasing the root log level and goinf through it, I've found the following:

```
2021-06-22 18:44:59,357 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) Deployment scan of [/home/xxxx/wildfly-23.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments] found update action [{
    "operation" => "composite",
    "address" => [],
    "steps" => [
        {
            "operation" => "add",
            "address" => [("deployment" => "togather-engine.ear")],
            "content" => [{
                "archive" => false,
                "path" => "deployments/XXXX.ear",
                "relative-to" => "jboss.server.base.dir"
            }],
            "persistent" => false,
            "owner" => [
                ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
                ("scanner" => "default")
            ]
        },
        {
            "operation" => "deploy",
            "address" => [("deployment" => "XXXX.ear")],
            "owner" => [
                ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
                ("scanner" => "default")
            ]
        }
    ],
    "operation-headers" => {"rollback-on-runtime-failure" => false}
}]
```

After a bit

```
2021-06-22 18:45:11,886 DEBUG [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) Deployment scan of [/home/xxxxx/wildfly-23.0.2.Final/standalone/deployments] found update action [{
    "operation" => "redeploy",
    "address" => [("deployment" => "XXXX.ear")],
    "owner" => [
        ("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner"),
        ("scanner" => "default")
    ]
}]
```

It looks that it's actually that is going through the deployment twice.

Comment: What I see is your application being undeployed. because of some JDBC issue I think since we can see that the MySQL driver is being undeployed before the server can resume.

Comment: @ehsavoie I did a quick test running a very basic project. Basically, I craeted a dummy EAR with the archetype Wildfly provides (`wildfly-jakartaee-ear-archetype`). I did not change anything, but I still obtain the same result. I don't think the issue is the Postgre driver.